# solving a matrix 2x2 Shell script for?

Tags: linux, matlab, shell

I was wondering if there is any way to solve a matrix 2x2 using shell script in Linux. I have created a simple code using Matlab and would like to to the same using shell script. The Matlab code is as follows;

```
R = 0.509515; 
R1 = 0.559467; 
R2 = 0.579594; 
L = 0;
L1 = -0.08568; 
L2 = 0.13974; 
y = [R1-R;R2-R];
x = [L1^2 L1;L2^2 L2];
c = x\y;
```

Also, is there any way to create a linspace like that in Matlab for the following command;

```
x=linspace(L1,L2,20)
```

Thanks in advance for the kind help.

Comment: Please include the desired output.

Comment: Install Matlab, save your script as `script.m`, then execute it via `matlab`, e.g. `matlab -r "run /path/to/script.m"`

Comment: Well, I said using shell script but thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: you can use python with numpy for that.

Comment: Would you please show me an example?